# Link gridviews for paging?

Tags: gridview

I implemented HectorMac's Suggestion, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254075/aspnet-grid-with-frozen-columns , but i have paging enabled since I have many records... I wanted to know if anyone has, or can guide me how I might link the two gridviews, so when I advance the page on one grid, the other will advance as well...

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanged.aspx